# Safari 15.0 on the Mac keeps on reopening closed windows

Tags: macos, safari

I'm running the new Safari 15 on MacOS 11.6 (Big Sur) and when I close the software and reopen it, the windows I've closed in the prior session reopen unlike before I upgraded Safari to the latest release.

I've tried emptying the caches. There's over 50GB of storage space. The system has plenty of unused RAM. Safari hung the first time I tried opening it after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can set or change this behaviour in Safari Preferences ("General" tab, the option right below setting Safari as the standard browser). But apparently you can't really stop it.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior was so problematic for me and my productivity that I decided to try and install Safari 15.1 beta. That has solved the problem for me.